# Call STT based on customer response

Tags: asterisk

I am placing calls to the customers using my own custom Asterisk Dialer,
When the customer picks up the call and starts speaking with us, the following are the cases.

- The first response of customer has of the length of 3 seconds, the system responds
- The second response of customer has of the length of 10 seconds, the system responds

Ideally, the system should call first STT API after 3 seconds when customers take a pause after completion of his sentence/response and second STT API after 10 seconds when customers take a pause after completion of his sentence/response

How do we achieve this? Our current dialer is calling STT API after a fixed interval of 3 seconds after the customers receive the call.

Comment: You'd better have proper streaming recognition instead of those fixed calls.

Comment: Can you please give some more details for streaming recognition?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/streaming-recognize

Comment: There are other more convenient implementations too